# Is there any way to prevent input type=“number” getting more than one dot values?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to get only decimal values like 1.5,0.56 etc. but  its allowing more than one dot.  is there any way to prevent it

[image]

Comment: With only HTML? No. But using JavaScript is not a sin.

Comment: with JavaScript  not a problem.

Comment: Where is going these submit? Maybe could you work with the number sended choosing only the elements before a second dot?

Comment: Not neccessary javascript since html5 have `pattern` attribute, check my answer

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pattern` attribute:

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([\.,][0-9]+)?">
```

It will allow patterns with a single dot, or even a comma (european decimals for example). To remove the comma, should be:

```
 <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]+([\.][0-9]+)?">
```

Comment: still its allowing more than one dot

Comment: You can write anything, but if you write something out of the pattern the input will not be valid and the form will not be submitted. That's the way that new HTML5 forms works. In my opinion, better than control input with javascript.

Comment: That is already the case for the number type without the pattern. I don't see any additional benefit here.

Comment: @trincot Correct, input pattern is not meant to work with input type="number" - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 1):

Originally shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62070691/1692889)

You can find very detailed explainations [in this Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/vYNqZNO)

This solution is simple and will only allow one dot in the number field. It doesn't prevent from clicking back in the number and adding numbers before the `"."`. It doesn't prevent from executing browser keyboard shortcuts like refresh, copy and pasting (as long as the pasted value is a valid number) and others. It will allow to add `"."` withing the body of the number, but will remove any exceeding floats over the set limit.

The only behavior that I still can't prevent is if you press the dot key at the end of the input repeatedly, the dot will blink on and off. This happens because a typed value of `"13."` is a valid number and returns `"13"` and a typed value of `"13.."` is not and returns "". In my solution, if a value returns `""` without the press of backspace or delete, it gets rolled back to the last valid value, wich is `"13"`, obtained from the typed value `"13."`.

I've tried solutions where if a dot was pressed once, it was prevented to be triggered a second time, but every time I managed to get stuck with pressing the dot right after an already existing dot followed by nothing and then get stuck with not being able to type a dot unless I pressed any other key first.

I think the blinking on multiple press is the best solution for ther's no way a user would type a dot and nothing happens.

```js
let lastValidInputValue;
let selectedDot = false;


const onKeypress = (e) => {
  if (e.key === "." && e.target.value.indexOf(".") !== -1 && !selectedDot) e.preventDefault();
  selectedDot = false;

  if (e.key === "e") e.preventDefault();
};


const onInput = (e) => {
  if (
    e.target.value.indexOf(".") < e.target.value.length - e.target.getAttribute("data-toFixed") - 1 &&
    e.target.value.indexOf(".") !== -1
  ) {
    let newValue;
    newValue = e.target.value.slice(
      0,
      e.target.value.indexOf(".") +
        parseInt(e.target.getAttribute("data-toFixed")) +
        1
    );
    newValue = parseFloat(newValue);
    e.target.value = newValue;
  }
  if (e.target.value !== "") {
    lastValidInputValue = e.target.value;
  } else if (e.inputType.match(/delete/g)) {
    lastValidInputValue = "";
  } else {
    e.target.value = lastValidInputValue;
  }
};

 const onSelect = (e) => {
   if(window.getSelection().toString().indexOf(".") > -1) selectedDot = true;
 }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="myNumber" name="myNumber" data-toFixed="2" step="any" onkeypress="onKeypress(event)" oninput="onInput(event)" onselect="onSelect(event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's old one. I'm not sure that you need overcomplicate solution with checking indexOf and so on...

What I needed (and what I show here) is to limit user to input (pos/negative) numbers with at most 2 decimals, no letters, no double dots or other stuff.

```html
<input type="text" value="0"/>
```

```js
$("input").on('input', function(e){
    let {value} = e.target;
    let processedValue = value
            .replace(/[^\d.\-]/, "")
            .replace(/^([\-]{0,1})(\d*)((\.\d{0,2}){0,1})(.*)$/g, "$1$2$3")
    $("input").val(processedValue);
  });
```

My regex could be a bit rough but it works. In short it's cleaning anything that is not number and dot, and then takes only first part with dot.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplest code to prevent multiple dots and it's also prevent some other invalid values:

```
$('input[type=number]').on('keydown', function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if ((keyCode == 190 || keyCode == 110) && (e.currentTarget.validity) && (!e.currentTarget.validity.valid))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use JavaScript to capture any change in the input value, and check whether the `inputAsNumber` property is still a valid number. If not, you could revert to the previous value:

```js
restoreData = {};

inp.oninput = preventTwoDots;
restoreData['inp'] = inp.value;

function preventTwoDots() {
    if (isNaN(this.valueAsNumber) && this.selectionStart) {
        this.value = restoreData['inp'];
    }
    restoreData['inp'] = this.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="inp">
```

The extra check on `selectionStart` makes sure that you can still remove all digits: an empty input is considered an invalid number, but it would be strange to not be able to delete the last character from the input.

#### Remarks

Although this is what you asked for in your question, please note that blocking user input is not particularly user-friendly. Browsers give visual clues when the input is not valid (on committing the value, for instance when you leave the input field), which generally is how it should be done. You don't want people to think their keyboard is failing, or let them think the clipboard is empty because their copy/paste is "not working".